# Java crypto API vs. different platforms

Tags: java, interop, cryptography

I have an Android application, which uses `javax.crypto` to encrypt some text data in files. Encryption implementation is similar to [this](http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.rhtml). The application works fine with the encrypted data it previously created.

Now, I almost ported my Android application to desktop (JFace/SWT). I'm using the same encryption implementation for the ported application, as it does not depend on any Android-specific API. The ported application works fine with encrypted data it created.

The problem is that desktop application cannot decrypt data, which was saved with Android application. The Android application fails to decrypt data, which was saved with desktop application as well. I double checked bytes streams of plain data and password to encrypt on both platforms. They are the same, so there are no problems with text encoding or so. But encryption routine return different encrypted results on different platforms even input data is byte-to-byte identical.

Does Java crypto API guarantees the same operation on different platforms? Should an encryption provider (AES/128bit in my case) work the same way on Android, Linux and Windows? Is there a way to tune `javax.crypto` to get interoperability on different platforms?

Comment: The encryption algorithms are very well-defined. There _shouldn't_ be a difference in the output bytes if the input is byte-for-byte identical, and the Java encryption method calls are the same.

Comment: If you show the code which you are using to encrypt/decrypt, we can maybe show the problematic point.

Comment: You're blaming the API but I'd bet it's a bug in your program.

Comment: Paŭlo, you can see the code if you click on the link in the question. Actual code is very similar to it. GregS, I'm not blaming the API. Currently, I found the different providers is used on Android and on the desktop for AES and for SHA1PRNG algorithms. I see the different secure keys is generated on different platforms for the same password. I'm trying to switch desktop application to the providers, which is used on Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AES-128 should work the same on both systems.  In theory.

In practice there are a lot of details that need to be the same on both systems.

- are you using the same padding at both sides?
- are you using the same mode (CBC, CTR, ECB) at both sides?
- do you have *exactly* the same password at both sides?
- do you have the same IV/Nonce at both sides?
- do you have the same key derivation method on both sides?

Check any defaults on both systems.  If the defaults don't match then you will need to set one side or the other explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm glad to hear there is a chance to make the applications work with encryted data of each other. I will try to find information about all these CBC, CTR, ECB, paddings, IV/Nonce, derivations and how to set them with `javax.crypto`. And yes, I used the same password at both sides. I triple checked byte streams of passwords on both systems.

Comment: If you can, avoid ECB as it isn't properly secure.  As to the passwords, check that both sides are using the same text encoding.  For example, if one side is UTF-8 while the other is UTF-16 then although the passwords may look the same, they will not be the same.

Comment: A different way of recasting @rossum's wise advice is: never rely on defaults. Always specify all aspects of the transform fully. Always specify the charset when en/decoding strings, and even better, always use UTF-8. And never, ever, use String as a container for random bytes.

Comment: My desktop system is Ubuntu, so both Android and desktop use UTF-8 encoding. But that's no matter, as I checked bytes array of passwords and data before and after encryption. Do anybody know how to get the default mode and padding for AES algorithm? I need that to maintain backward compatibility. cipher.getIV() returns 'null' on both systems.

Comment: Finally I got it worked! Thanks everyone for ideas! At first I changed AES provider for the desktop application to one, which is used on Android (Bouncy Castle). That was easy, but did not change the results. Next, I changed SHA1PRNG implementation to Android one (Apache Harmony). That was not too easy, but it works now! Actually SUN and Harmony implementations of SHA1PRNG return different results on secureRandom.nextLong() just after the same secureRandom.setSeed(seed).

Comment: Why does your program rely on PRNGs returning a reproducible sequence? That can be nice for simulations, but it's likely wrong for crypto.

Comment: The answer is simple - because I found an easy to use implementation, which I pointed in the question. I wonder which algorith should I use instead of SHA1PRNG (it should be available on Android of course)?

Answer (score 3):

It is a mistake to depend on a cryptographically-random number generator generating the same random numbers on different platforms.  Normally, the cryptographic random salt used in a key-derivation algorithm has to be communicated from sender to receiver.  It might be communicated as a secret, but it does need to be communicated.  The "master password" is the main secret, of course.

One way these salts are often communicated is as a prefix on the ciphertext.  That makes the ciphertext longer than the plaintext, but I don't think that matters in your sample technique.

Also, for a full-up encrypted-message exchange, other parameters of the encryption need to be communicated to the decrypter.  You can wire those into your implementations, as you've done here, but depending on reproducibility seems too brittle.  It is of course something an attacker can replicate, of course, so it is not part of your secret.

You might want to rethink the key-generation algorithm setup to be something more robust.

Afterthought: What is happening in the current approach is a cryptographically-useful RNG is being used in a way where all the randomness has been removed!  The recommendation to check out PBKDF2 and key-derivation generally is a good one.

Comment: Related http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2

Comment: Good point: PBKDF2 is good to look at for what is needed here. Also the W3C XML Encryption specification will provide clues about the parameters that need to be communicated or else wired into all sending-receiving parties.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation to use PBKDF2. I see the problem with SHA1PRNG now. But, seems, Android has no integrated PBKDF2 implementation currently. I got `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SecureRandom PBKDF2 implementation not found`

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to show us some code. One frequent beginner mistake is to store the encrypted data in a String rather than the byte[] it came in. String isn't a container for binary data. This technique can fail in many ways including default charade differences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You can check the code if you click on the link in the question. The actual code is pretty close to the code on the link.